# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

How to solve this kind of error? And how to update gradle I'm using firebase Auth, firebase core and firebase database

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can try to pinpoint the cause of the error. Also providing some Gradle files may expedite the process.

Comment: i can't post the whole code if this error.."It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: but this is my dependencies

Comment: in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    //recyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //card view
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //picasso library to retrieve images
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    //firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    //firebase Storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    // Glide library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```